# Add some shortcuts to ESS jags mode

Tags: r, ess

I'm relatively new to emacs and bayesian data analysis and the JAGS software. 
I would like to modify the ess jags-d.el file in order to have the **F8** shortcut for **<-** ,as in the R-mode using ESS. IS it possible ?

I hope that my question it's clear, and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I don't see why not but you may be better off asking on the ESS list.

Comment: thank you, i'll follow your advice and ask on the ESS list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately   `ess-smart-underscore` will not work in bugs mode.

Simple answer would be:

```
(define-key ess-bugs-mode-map [f8] (lambda() (interactive) (insert " <- ")))
```

this just binds <kbd>f8</kbd> to insert `<-`.

To achieve exactly the same behavior in bugs as in ess put the following into your .emacs:

```
(define-key ess-bugs-mode-map (kbd "_") 'bugs-smart-underscore)

(defun bugs-smart-underscore ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((assign-len (length ess-S-assign)))
    (if (and
         (>= (point) (+ assign-len (point-min))) ;check that we can move back
         (save-excursion
           (backward-char assign-len)
           (looking-at ess-S-assign)))
        ;; If we are currently looking at ess-S-assign, replace it with _
        (progn
          (delete-backward-char assign-len)
          (insert "_"))
      (delete-horizontal-space)
      (insert ess-S-assign))))
```

Now, pressing <kbd>_</kbd> once will get you `<-`, twice - `_`.

Comment: Thank's a lot, now it's worked very well...for the F8 the mistake was mine, i had _ in my mind when i wrote the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't use JAGS, but as far as I can see in ESS manual:

> Changes/New Features in 5.4:
>
> ESS[BUGS] and ESS[JAGS]: typing = now
>   results in <-.

Comment: thank's for your answer, but i also read this on the ESS manual (version 5.13), but as a R user i often use and prefer to use <- instead of = (even if it's the same)

Comment: How about binding `M-x ess-smart-underscore`